# What is the meaning of phrase 'Let there be light, let there be life'

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is the meaning of given phrase, I have listen this in one movie. I am not able to make out. Can anybody tell me

> Let there be light, let there be life

Answer (score 1):

In addition to books4languages.com's reference to the humorous aspect of the phrase I find it appropriate to mention the AC/DC's song "Let There Be Rock" where this phrase is used in a similar humorous way

...

- Let there be sound

  - There was sound
- Let there be light

  - There was light
- Let there be drums

  - There was drums
- Let there be guitar

  - There was guitar

Oh, Let there be rock

...

Answer (score 0):

"let there be light" This phrase is spoken by God in the Bible during the creation story:

**1In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth. And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters. And God said, Let there be light: and there was light. And God saw the light, and it was good; and God divided the light from the darkness.**

If you have heard this in a religious sense then the speaker is referring to the Bible.

However, "Let there be light" (shortened) is sometimes said humorously when one switches on a light.